# How to rollback with 2 transaction in same method on Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, transactions

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;

    @Transactional
    public void save(String name) {
        method1(name);
        method2(name);
    }

public void method1(String name){
userRepository.save(name)
}

    public void method2(String name) {
        roleRepository.save(name);// Error
    }
}
```

```
public interface UserService {
    void save(String name) throws Exception;
}

@PostMapping("/save")
    public void save() throws Exception {

        userService.save("SomeThing");
    }
```

I have 2 methods in the save method. As you can see, the method2 has an error.

I run the program, the first method prints to the database. However, if the second method is incorrect, I want the rollback process to fall and the first method not to be written to the database. How can I do it?

I tried to use `@Transaction` annotation on method1 and method2 but it error continued. And i tried `Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW`, and `Propagation.REQUIRED`, `TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly();` never changed.

Comment: I won't recommend double `@Transactional`.

Comment: there is just a single transaction on the `save` method the whole tx either succeeds or fails. If it doesn't, you have something weird in your tx setup OR are using a DB that doesn't support transactions. Are you using MySQL with MyISAM tables (as those don't support transactions).

Comment: Where are you calling `save` from, and what is the definition of `UserService`?

Comment: Sandeep, i remove the first Transactional but error doesnt change. @M.Denium, i use mysql. chrylis -on strike- i change my code

Comment: Check your tables, if they are of the MyISAM type they aren't transactional, use InnoDB types for transaction s upport.

Comment: Thank you so much. I changed type to InnoDB and it worked.

Comment: MyISAM was the worst thing to happen to databases before the invention of NoSQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is totally logical what you are trying to do. Just rollingback when one part of your flow fails is normal.

I'll give more background to make sure you have everything:

- `@Transactional` only rollback, by default, when a `RuntimeException` is thrown. You can customize this. Check the doc, it is very easy to find out. Be careful, make sure you use `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional`. You have more options with this one.
- Understanding propagation is key. By default, the propagation of `@Transactional` is `Required`, which means it will either joins an existing transaction, or creates a new one. `Requires_New` always create a new one. In your case, `Propagation.REQUIRED` is the good one.
- Once you are in a Transactional method, adding `@Transactional` on other method inside your class and make inner call won't have any effect. The transaction starts when you enter in your method from the outside of your class. Once you in your class, the others annotations won't affect the runtime.

Three things/questions to consider:

- What kind of error is throwing the `RoleRepository.save(...)` ?
- What is the context ? Is it a test ? Is it a running application ? Could you provide more code ?
- As said in one comment, read this: [Spring Transaction Management with Hibernate and MySQL, Global and Local](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717935/spring-transaction-management-with-hibernate-and-mysql-global-and-local). You could have some issues with that as well...

Comment: Hi, the first of all, I changed MySql table type to InnoDB and it worked. Thanks for information, i just learning to transaction management. The error is a basic validation error. the method2 size min parameters is 3 and string value has length bigger tahn 3. And this is a rest application and i didnt use the test. I changed my question and added rest controller. Thank you so much for the Link i will read. Thanks

Comment: if it worked for you, don't forget to mark the answer was correct.